# Html.AjaxBeginForm not calling the Action in the Controller in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-ajax, umbraco

I've been going through the headache of upgrade Umbraco CMS from 9 to 11+ .Net Core.  I seem to be having issues with a Predictive Search function now not calling the controller action.  I can't seem to figure out what I need to do?  Is Html.AjaxBeginForm not working in Core? Appreciate any insight.

Partial View for Search Text Box:

```
@model SearchViewModel
@using Site.Models

@using (Html.AjaxBeginForm("SubmitSearchForm", "Search", null, new AjaxOptions {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
     OnBegin = "progress",
     OnComplete = "progress",
     UpdateTargetId = "preSearchWrapper"
     }, new { id = "search_form", name = "search_form", role = "search" })) {
    <div class="search input-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchTerm, new { @placeholder = "Search...", @id = "SearchTerm", @class = "input-group-field", @tabindex = "1", @type = "search", @autocomplete = "off" })

        <div class="input-group-button">
            <input type="submit" class="button" tabindex="2" value="" id="submit-button" title="submit search" aria-label="search submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="preSearchWrapper">
      
    </div>
    }
```

Search Controller:

```
using Examine;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Web;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.Controllers;
using Umbraco.Cms.Web.Common.PublishedModels;
using Site.Helpers;
using Site.Models;

namespace Site.Controllers {
    public class SearchController : RenderController {
        public IPublishedContentQuery _contentQuery { get; private set; }
        private readonly IExamineManager _examineManager;
        private readonly UmbracoHelper _umbracoHelper;
        private SearchHelper _searchHelper { get { return new SearchHelper(_contentQuery, _examineManager); } }

        public SearchController(
              ILogger<SearchController> logger,
              IPublishedContentQuery contentQuery,
              IExamineManager examineManager,
              ICompositeViewEngine compositeViewEngine,
              IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor,
              UmbracoHelper umbracoHelper
           )
          : base(logger, compositeViewEngine, umbracoContextAccessor) {
            _contentQuery = contentQuery;
            _examineManager = examineManager;
            _umbracoHelper = umbracoHelper;
            }

        private string PartialViewPath(string name)
            {
            return $"~/Views/Partials/Search/{name}.cshtml";
            }

        
        public IActionResult SubmitSearchForm(SearchViewModel model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SearchTerm)) {
                    model = _searchHelper.GetSearchResults(model.SearchTerm.Replace("*", "").Replace("?", ""), _umbracoHelper.CultureDictionary.Culture.Name.ToString());
                    }
                }
                return RenderSearchResults(model);
            }

        public IActionResult RenderSearchResults(SearchViewModel model) {
            return PartialView(PartialViewPath("_PredictiveSearchResults"), model);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please open develop tools in chrome browser, and check the network detail. Check what happend when click the submit button.